# Trying to join three tables, keep getting error 00933 (Oracle Apex)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to query three tables showing Japanese sumo results from the years 2017 through 2019, filtered by the highest rank.

```
Select a.*, b.*, c.* 
from sumo_2019 a 
where Rikishi1_Rank like 'Y%'
join sumo_2018 b on a.Rikishi1_ID = b.Rikishi1_ID
join sumo_2017 c on b.Rikishi1_ID = c.Rikishi1_ID
```

I keep getting this error

> 00933 SQL Command not properly ended.

I've tried changing the joins to Full Outer and left with no success (I'm trying to show all wrestlers with rank 'Y%', regardless of whether or not they appear on other tables). I keep receiving the same error.

Comment: Don't you rather need a `UNION` than the `JOIN`?

Answer (score 2):

The WHERE clause comes after the joins, not before

Comment: That solved it. Sorry I'm still new